# Why isn't my component property available in my service callback function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have declared a variable now trying to assign a value but it throws error , How it works in tyoescript does it work in strict mode and hoisted. What is correct approach to resolve this issue ?

Also if i push item to array in javascript it does not add element to array ?

main.component.ts

```
export class SlaChartComponent implements OnInit  {
  constructor(private chartService: ChartService, private detailService: DetailService) { };

      public barChartLabels:string[] = [];

      ngOnInit(){
           this.messageArray = [];
           this.detailService.currentMessage2.subscribe(message2 => {
              this.chartService.getChart().subscribe(chartObj => {
                 console.log('DataChart',chartObj);
                   chartObj.forEach(function(item){
                      this.barChartLabels = item.date;
                   })

                 });


        })
      }
```

Error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'barChartLabels' of undefined
```

Comment: in your foreach callback your not in the context of the component

Comment: The innermost `function` needs to be an arrow function to preserve `this`

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

Comment: Is it a compile error or runtime error, and what is the exact error text? What compiler options did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
chartObj.forEach(function(item){
    this.barChartLabels = item.date;
})
```

For this:

```
chartObj.forEach((item) => {
    this.barChartLabels = item.date;
});
```